# EnterpriseCDF tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

There is so much confusion and terseness about CDF / EnterpriseCDF.
In light of questions like: 
[How to make a CDF document with dynamic content?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17249/how-to-make-a-cdf-document-with-dynamic-content)

I think there should be a tag EnterpriseCDF (or CDF-licensing? or CDF-signing?),
just to clarify the (somewhat complex and changing) set of rules of what FreeCDF does and what not (in V9 ...)

Answer (score 2):

This sounds sensible if there is enough demand for it. The simplest way to create a tag is to post a question with that tag: [you have enough reputation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/privileges/create-tags) to do this. The tag wiki would be a good place to keep track of certain factual information. Although you [do not currently have enough reputation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) to edit tag wikis without someone else approving those edits, that is a straightforward process and you should definitely feel free to add such information without fear that it creates work for people - it’s just a couple of clicks.

An alternative solution would be to tag such things with the [licence](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/licence) tag, as well as the [cdf-format](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cdf-format) tag.